# Why does the Web API controller get null data from client through POST request?

Tags: c#, angularjs, post, asp.net-web-api, angular-resource

I have an AngularJS app sending an object array to a Web API controller method through a POST request. On the server I have the following method definition:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Active")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(IList<Media> mediaFiles)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var file in mediaFiles)
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => PublicData.SetInactiveMedia(file.Id, file.Active));
        }
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {

        return BadRequest(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I use the $resource factory in order to interact with the server (but I have to mention that I have also tried with $http and no difference showed up). This is the method:

```
var activeMedia = $resource('/api/adminhotspotsmedia/active', { save: { method: 'POST' } });
var setActiveMedia = function (mediaFiles) {
            activeMedia.save(mediaFiles);
        }
```

The `mediaFiles` variable is an array of objects that absolutely match the `Media` model on the server.

In the Developer's Console I can see this Request Payload associated with the request:

[image]

So the array is trying to get to the server, but it cannot. The server gets a null value for the list of objects. I will add that I have tried using:

- `[FromBody]` tag
- `dynamic` instead of `IList<Media>`
- `IList<object>` instead of `IList<Media>`

The problem persists. What could it be?

Comment: Don't use interface. the model binder wont know what to do with it unless you have a custom model binder. It needs concrete classes to bind to so use concrete objects. so either use an actual `List<Media>` or array `Media[]`

Answer (score 0):

By default the model binder wont know what to do with the interface unless you have a custom model binder that knows what to expect and what the desired behavior is.

Alternatively you can use an actual `List<Media>`

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Active")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(List<Media> mediaFiles) { ... }
```

or array `Media[]`

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Active")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Media[] mediaFiles) { ... }
```

Comment: I had switched from `List` to `IList` before right because I hadn't understood the behavior. Now I've tried both your suggestions and they don't work.